# Yammer API - Clearing the seen messages count

Tags: yammer

I'm making a yammer app that pulls messages from Yammer to be displayed offsite.

Is there a way through the yammer dev api to mark messages as seen, so that when you visit yammer, they don't still have that "unread" counter?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

The unread count changes when a user engages with Yammer. There isn't an API that lets you mark messages as read since doing this on behalf of a user could result in them missing information, or other problems. Social applications have certain user expectations and as a developer you can break these expectations. That is a big driver for how and what Yammer APIs are available.

If you are only pulling messages from Yammer, then [Data Export API](https://developer.yammer.com/docs/data-export-api) may be the most useful option.

Answer (score 1):

There is an api endpoint called `messages/last_seen_in_thread.json` which is not documented. It can be used to 'mark as read'.

**Caution**: Since it is not documented in the official API it may be subject to change and thus may eventually break.

I am using it as follows:

```
yam.platform.request({
    url: "messages/last_seen_in_thread.json",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
        thread_id: thread_id,
        message_id: message_id
    },
    success: data => { },
    error: msg => { }
});
```

Just specify the thread id and message id in the data parameter.